# How do I maximize the Ubuntu screen when it is a Virtualbox guest?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, screen

I am VirtualBox on windows 7.

The VM has Ubuntu32bit (latest version) running.

I am unable to maximimze the Ubuntu window.

Here's a screen shot of what I see:

[image]

Please, please go easy on me! I'm a microsoft guy, and JUST started with linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Comment: Yes, guest additions would do it.

Comment: I think this question is not a duplicate, because I would never have thought of fossfreedom's solution when asking the question. The link is not evident at first.

Comment: @fossfreedom i did as stated in the link you provided and no change, i will now take the suggestion below thanks!

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing any other suggestions??

Answer (score 4):

As fossfreedom indicates in a comment, it is better to install the Virtualox Guest Additions first. See this question to do so: [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).

After that, if you still have your problem, try changing the resolution of Ubuntu inside Ubuntu:

- Go to the Dash Menu (the big Ubuntu button in the top-left corner).
- Then type "Resolution" or "Displays" to see the "Displays" app.
- Launch it by clicking on it.
- You should then be able to augment the resolution.

Comment: thank you ! the max display has already been set at 1024x768! what else shoudl i try? i did get the guest additions. do i need to restart windows?

Comment: It should be sufficient to restart your Ubuntu guest for additions to take effect. Then turn *fullscreen* with <hostkey> + F or *scale mode* with <hostkey> + A (hostkey is <right Ctrl> key in your case).

Comment: thank you very much, that did SOMETHING, it made the background of virtualbox instead of grey, it made it black, but the linux is still th esame size

Answer (score 3):

here's what worked!!

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
```

Comment: funny how hard you need to dig to find a solution to a problem that is very widely encountered. i guess google's algorithm isnt perfect

Comment: It's no longer "ose" now, just `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`. It pulls in dkms.